# how to randomly assign proxy for curl?

Tags: php, proxy, curl

i want my curl to use random proxy from the proxy.txt file that is saved in my site with this format:

```
1.1.1.1:8080
2.2.2.2:8080
3.3.3.3:8080
...
```

I want it to make it randomly so that every time it uses different proxy from the proxy.txt list, but i have no idea i can code something like that in php.

Answer (score 1):

Read a random line from a file:

```
srand ((double)microtime()*1000000);
$f_contents = file ("proxy.txt");
$line = $f_contents[array_rand ($f_contents)];
print $line;
```

All you need now is:

```
function get_random_proxy()
{
    srand ((double)microtime()*1000000);
    $f_contents = file ("proxy.txt");
    $line = $f_contents[array_rand ($f_contents)];
    return $line;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but wanted to share this:

Basically the static variable `$proxys` only gets set once, and remembers the array pointer, so each time you call `change_proxy()` it will give you the next in file and then return to the start when it has cycled once.

```
function change_proxy()
{
  static $proxys = file('./proxy.txt', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES|FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

  $proxy = current($proxys);
  $end = next($proxys); # false when end
  if(!$end) {
    reset($proxys);
  }
  return $proxy;
}
```